# Scale domain bounds not being set

Tags: vega-lite

I have a corner case visualization here where the domain is not being set to the bounds---it does work if I set the values to something else, like [0, 2000], or [0,4000], but curiously not to the values I want.

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgYATgGtsYYJDwBPQsn1HG8PaqjwJhfQEYAvuoiQA7owAmLfQCcAAxB7lDISvDcPoxK1PqgEB4AHgkaSVAAZozIYj4WWrnoeIxUACqMqMgAIoyZmWrpSUam5jiQAI6s6EoleMWl5mEZkOjJjLAJlnhibWBBbk0eCOizUz7cGLH6ANqhYABMQcEAui5NiyPGaRke2bn57WLc1NTIWgCS+cPNJmYW3C0MSUq0atygYwmUz6axw+0s1kmcNskDE6HYuSR83OGUuzSizy0N1ukHueQs6HgJWUAGFEOgtHgwSS-nNIEpNrFQT9lvBVnNEuCoBstiocDsliSEFpuGIxMyhXZosgwHhuGBYnh3pTqSoeSSoj4hpKRprtVSeEpVerDcbFctcsgLcoFULINodBtPHqTc1WIwwFFejL5b6TvqPFoem9dr6PBJqPhqFHrhHmgBiHwANgOAHYDgAOV3gyDp+q5zJBO320tOTK53PsaTFknppyNp0NNMedMBaRZxvfONQdPseDsHwHA6QMOSnFJPEebiESnMa44QwUVasOZBOgAVnneMgQey8Q3CL0F5YVh0SmQsCxrmPPmKmA3TUgW7EO6xEvBgoljqlp0gyTLtLaLbxi8byfI84TJGYWiVBEeAAPpOAEaHIN+aEYrojrGGhhCylY1YloUaIlOUKG1PU+h7kE7YhCxrFBPueb7nO+qASSwG0vSjIWNKsrymmqIwe8XwWMgiHvChvQYVhOGrHh7w6IRxGkfA5EkpRAw0VUdENDgU50LmfZsWxARZtxkq8SM-FKKBQntCJcpQVAzyvFJ8GQLJSEKehmHYbh+EabMREkRIOmeZA+nUcgFRGXUJmHFmdAAMy5lmAR5flBX7pldkAb6ozOs5gngVA7liWV3mwdJ7QBfJVSKSFKliGpBGRVpMW6SMCWDMlNSpfo-Z0H2BwFTNAQFtIJW3A5zROS51WQLVcUNb5MlychbXBcpYXqZp0VkXFQ2GaN9E4EVdDSAc+6zQVxXgouSTLR4q1VRYHpej6ioST5cG7YFB1KaFqnhad2kDc0l1JbRY23fudDtkcVksY9i0ZJ9EIVWtwnwCGdWA9tIPNXtQUQ513URcgUWwxdRSJSNxn6PuGU5bmmMsVxb08WV31gUTJNbZJFMIWDqE08dPUM3153iQjbPI2AWZOHQWb9s9+WZfztzvRAePlbqhNucToni8DTVS61MsdXL9OM-1zNUcNSM3ershZhrvMhLZAv2ULBM-RbYvieTtv+VT4OO1DJ29WdsXKyzHspV7A5a1mmX+0xOMfSHZthzVlseZHEvRy1+0O0dCfyy7StlSrntpTzdAFlmBa63lTgF8bRcgSX7oMp63DetbjV+dX1Px110NJ0zqfu1d7M4PmaOFj3AT9wYg8CSL4dWxXNvT7HteQ-PicK8ncORmnq9q7mPtBBZPcG7iguA8LrmlxH9WVzPtLdqdcr4N0VinZuD9EYZzbrmcyQRpo91zLvE2P91qQRPlPUG9sQGXzpjDV2y8DIwOum3AI90CyYWQag-elVD5QDNFGCq1pAzKknjtSmwDDr4IXjfJeUCV6kLXmACyWspx5xQUHUq39Q4MI2mXUmboo5ANwTw2mfDG6QMBi3WB+gCyoycE4aQedXqGy-m6dBwlHQVQ4ZLGO3DZb12dhAu+UBdFkMCPAgITgMa8zMZ-YOsji7yM2lgzhdsa54I0dfLRbj4rQNVl7OadBEHbwCFI8xQTLFyN-htGxuo7FV3PtEp2hCm46MSa3ZwQRZCv1zv7He0ilp0PNn-Y+ADT44Kieospi8iGCJIUktKThalZX1nnBazTcatOHmEzp2CuFqKcWAlxt83ZDOqTgUZFCP4LgsUBXJ61-RsODLKIpqiekrIIf0ipboPEiKMQcOgRxMrbz2RAI2e9glD1CYoi53TZ6gJufwgZlShHDOcL4juTgsymNoT8g+eSTlBjwCGAFSyrlzxBXEjZrMtlgCMajPs0ht5TKyTInJITkUBlRei8J9iZ5x2BZo1xeL06eO2ZhF5wQyUIqpb8vJ8yyaAMBcy3hsS2XEPxXo7ZBxNbPyQbrclgTKWHOpetYVyjRWYqBRK8B6zpUcseYWDuBjt6ZNVS0xF9ChX-IZcUxx2LWWGsGTKzlhLMqa2CA03mBx+XqsFZq+1CyIkOOWc6yVrrwWbNlZ6gsHdHp5w+WAL5aCjmiw6SKrpurxUxINQImN7rHnSG9QOf2fdpmFxtW0hR-9s2LMiXq-NazC33KqXG4xqMggDm3gWANfEM1H3LqGxlJTenOPKdo9tEKCXGITdlXK78B2OSHe0kdDaw1Movi2qd8SHlqycPuBV+4eb+0DhS61AqkUYPYQ6y5za+mgruRRDtHqj3PNee8ldK0111qzdqnNTa81PtxUax+XtYXPIegE-Z2TA03szRuwDjbw1YpZVGttr7Z2dtzJle6cLJk-q+n+rVJYVFip3aBqVbrjWHrEfufsybiP4w1UhpR5GdXAao5O2507sOxvfQYg8eGK0sdNkG9jGLuOlN48+-jek32PO7qkpwbye7iascOjjJIKO5p46svd7KIMjICPhvK6ndaVsvTMmtcyQ2brHU6jDBawUzsEyIjGLy3nwqrQPOz8jMGjsdRGlzra3MCeLWrI48DMqZRMeezTpGHMoa3eO65LqsOKZwx6o4Cae3pJVXBtVg62Paek2hx9cmwO0ZM-oeV0HfG+Zs9W69trg31tS050L+rwsvuyx56L7ZUl5iI3575bXa1BccyF9DvWjPgeEUN-Lp687+vG+msr66dMjD0zJidhm+P7qU9F+VB4Qh9qS1tk8d7gsPpA9VmjRa6NeynKjA4XqruSfK-eyjsnDvyeOzlzzj1Jq+t5heq1tnJv2c65xoDlWHsA5q89urplc6pOkP2jbszAu3Zm-dgzOKnvuai69jHcXwdWWxy1-zMO-lw901xxHRPMsRYG2TtKBxpD4ZMaSmhOOAt2sZ7t5n27-vE+jaTl7XPpDwOPQWZrUPWsIfa1J37+mJds-64NE7r3j2pICH4qy1nld09V7WsjTOEfi4O5LrLuvgfRf3O9uaX3EM-bu39u32uFOO8G69jWWtYXu7V57gn3uMuYfZ-7zn9WcpZQMaHqb+Ouuzaq8jknkWZfx92UERX-siufIOaV7722Ku26j65nX8M9dc8V2jMz29IfFavRb2HAH4eocr5G6vfva9O9ewWfDz9LPPWTx35DXe0vOfm0d4zS2h-y-W7Tib7eGed+t939Lve+v9-voPrnPiEH891hPvHRoK877Cwt2ri+j8KpzNvc-wvN+i5t9fufgOF+QtMhk1J2USure0O6+r+U+W+M+PWu68+i2v+YAucsg00xwPcReqaJeq61202aehOWu0eNeB+AeaUuc8uuY+4zGgu9OYBO2zQe2LOuBfeQOhB+gucCaR6S6Z+FBoBHWb+NBYun+0B3+sBBKXqzyRiVObELexe8GpeHu5eGu+2Vee+jBceOAmURwk0NOZua+MhYechXumuPueB++7idezB3OABCWmMpuwBKuOhluKW0+3Wc2AhKO0uaO8BeYaM+ez+nBdhk+1B0EH+s+LhWeHOOeqhGO7Yp+z0KaaauOeSWBjh6eSO9uMeA+TBER+GR6BeVhsGUhJWGBZe-64B7+2+wR1GUu2e7hcWCaAQRUL+t6l+8hdBhhDBP+whmUtRBiYmvhhRshN2TR+hChu+t+qO9+zBJiaMaheckhaB0hfRuhxRARXkfB5Rj2lRYR1Rpak0TeGmvRv612f048AM2BkeIxMBd+cBmUQeXqyBHBq+m2RRVupRkBzhFRDu6RKh8BQeHEhGvMlqNh5ufhG+JRvBQRUB7xaRBBXx1xsgLu4hLE1h+RbewJVBV+axmeGxse4R8B7cTgw+FqDR6uQxLRihoxbh4xqhCePib89xWhjx-RzxYJZREJ6xHx0JOJnRe4cKxubESJcxBRBxTxDhEBThGeqR+BJhh+zBwm2sfasxcRQu3BoJgRLJbxbJUJUpGR8BeUqSuYoyvMxiRJ4epxBhZJFxYxcBJizyDYSq4++xJG12TJqprx4pvuyhOJJiFCcuBpmMH2xpehEeZp5xghlxBKpaNpCp6BQpjJIpLxYpKR7p7RcapaqMOUT0usSeDprGwpIuzJrpiZRhHp7hD0e4z8TSDx8RypyxQMapbpRZyZHqMGHcQQY+M0ncAZAx8StBPeN+FpFJVpoORUORVk3OnZzpKx4J6pmJ7JWpXx0g0gqM-Y-JiplB1Z6JrJM5mpCS0pOAi55mBwfxJuUZ8xMZixKKygaK5yzRvZX+rhVRlJYAi5FCOYJ5gpjpRRF5ZyNZPZ-BkJkpO52pcuzyLuAJyJIBqJ65N5f5GpAFB6Xscu+GbyZ6Vhb5KJCx9heZLpCZrODZQhKZCePMCJIQK+9JVZFgiRopyRuFbR+FTZDYWURuPcmhgJ2hGFw8X5V5P5qxm5EpxhgF85BYohRiPRlZSpFgnF9KJJt5IRWJnxnpw+Ws1xfK2ZEmsZWFk5dZhZtFYZKZwmC57B9pYla5xJQZwxfZoZlp4ZBYCapBK50ZH56lPB2F1F9BShjZIipKzyr83cy6qlWmgZpp5ld5oR2JJZdRWUpB-spFrFDJixE5tZBZNF7ldFnlKSiF0VnZhosQ1ABwTCTkG505fFxZj5-OLySahpqBq5XBplQVpJIZ95mxj5ZBmsWOdps0sRDlOZTlKpmlSVbl5JD5cBZBGUrZ45cZ+ZOFA1-ZQ1BKZBFCuYVCmV-lyWGliVU1rRKVulHqx6xK-pK1TpE1LlOBm1g1TVw1ZkR61Cz0LF4Fth7FF+OVeVvQ5ohS0FGJxVHlasHEn6dxN141a1v5H1SZqV31pqi5MVd1QJD1CR0QT1+Vti71vFIN21IiHEFCtS0R7Z45BSlohV9ZOlVlcaRUmsLVANzlfVG15pllA5c1XqImYFAp6FZ5KewIuVCNb10lMFW5cFpht09NWYnMPhxlNV7QHNlorClF8Zrlp1M151dNj+bZM0ONswiNXNwNeFqN31nRWsWNs05NvV61Mt1NjVYVzVOteGt1TNEFMNUF6tyNmtRNO1D0qSBYKFo5Bt3FU5BNW1TtaNi5YO7tfJnZ4tygktqeSRJ1JtoV8l7h8JLyxiwtZF4lJpkdZxFlptsdzVd0j0R5wdB1uZFNRtUdDVMdHJcdT0SlvldJsV5FqdVFJdGdZdc5OJnMzy2stJRlydJl9d0tjdIVcl5dzVXc90R6y1ItkFtVadwZTdg9Ldcd+pHcStytBd-Rkl159tRVKNft31i14y7VK9E9ttU9Dd6dA9s5AlrdilH2wQ-int+N2lvttNxNbt5Vnd2Nq98VR1lNxtpdc9l9cdwQLyVCSdtdKdgV09wVslF98FaUhG2cZBfq99SNW9jtz9HqcKsgamlhHtn9mFRdQNDthN6DIicKsWOUyDm9PtZ1ZtcBGsiBbueD-hD9yVNDWddDw2JiedrEkN1t91LNzDKD1DcttDBKOYzygBoDUNbFAjIJXtWlrDIj7DYjQ5-YlDZl9Vs9MDfN6spqLu11XdYDPdEDp9M95925sD+gOc+G8qeRfD0NsjaJQjj9bDQ9dDkx+U6jdVMl-5-FljOA2sqMiuvpuDR9jjdtGjPjsFfjOj2sCa3c79h93dotJjfdZ90DFjsTd0pBvJPDXjkDmj5jvNu56snMMKVt1Vk9vdk1v9WjmTJTgtFCNlBjH9YTjlX9gNPFqDxDs1cavszyNJUj9jMj7T+DhthD3TT9vTGDWcQlxF+cTDoSuNLozjijNN0zpDG8cKiDfp+TpjUDvjJVdDG8czzFWVcNcQz1WozCnNkT3Nn1oNmcJzPmSDizeSodVoaobCgxdzGtPT8tfTG8RuuTLEdjlTx91Tx16ThzX1TzGUbtf1+tbzET3j9z29JDasvaOxnZ698j-Vst6zALGDVCWUTEQz4L4TFFEd+zhTGTxT2pXcms8WIT+dbT3VixHz4dPzqLfzUzRLpDJLx6KtTotzPLRDfLojfTil2Ut9VhezaTZjdLMTDTili5OzoTyTVTSobNVzr1eNqz01hLkrxL+GjGFTXValHLL1NzEtXzUtNT-dSrRzYjilS15LFrAVkAuLLDhrmdbjLrGURuI5rLmrELqTDr0L0TzrfT-+XcGZNd0jcVYzeLVNf92jJTPM8CTEvDFLozgjVDLjSj-rca+pjEh5ZzyLJ9CrBzUbsLbcamABy9njlbkLP9jrMLjz9bGU+Jl2LbUA3rBrBLfr89j5+Ysg8W1dhjibdd-btKl5Ulvz4rrjI7cB+YqMXqQdeTfbkAnLdr1L1btLHbWtXs+YFCRwsrJu8rEbirR7O9J700HcGS7rp5eb8iA7Bbazw7ADo7ahB4vs5z3LBTUTPNyr2peG7d2UV7ULN7tbnb+g4Hk0WOoloblLYt1rTkXL3ZXTwjRryjJbv7NkwbrE9lL77LluyzJxQHaLaDGzT8Otj0ODIbRjKTSxPrQ7zd37q7OtzLz775ZHw82VlzHzbH0d-9-joiOt9R27u7No+717NbIH0bHqlt5k5ZexbLlrybInab9TYHcuqnm7oLUHbbkbindb8HHEHcq2rzGnnrCVEzOHX74n6ZaMva6nKHr7NKpyXF2ndT9LXx3M5kjGyHzHWrrHg7on6bYH7cuUjHW7tnq1BD2HhbuHxbynCer8jNub-HcjvnRToHAXYifY3DiJxnxdpnDzx7bcilr8FZHnOXeSRxE8EXOn-nOJi1sgwL-sYLHriX4zyXn7HHznncB4+4RHWMZXDnKXTnOji1uycpmZnZTXlHNLwHlXd75CrV3O499Xmn+bi7kzy7nHBKFk8TPOFbCXhxo8-0eXTr5nOAiu8ChY6rTH074D4XH7vrQ3Ojj3qna2k3A3X3YnP3Rim8VVvXh1nT3t0333JTVCWDZmAP0Pg3wPcPw2uU43IQJHfHe3uXLXfnBXOJQle4iumPiCSPCjQPUXXxQlL86SFP+LkXunNPnhmbvHzNnnKLVHvLR34nw+ZZ+YO3oXYbI8ugN3+P+XSnIiw+J62PHPDXXPq31H-zxr0v8W5kNlQvb3xjH3B3jnsP2pw+3icWWvwzSb+3Yrh3RbK7BK80AzC3CbZvM7uvlv+vqPhvE0mEcXE3279ngP7H7vNPpKiHPXpHuPTjn3Af1PRPLujeofOPnr9r0HCn63GLXsBi8CA43vJFDPqbBPUvasBiCanM5rYfdn395XMHZncHD3QeTeIX2vLHSfJnVfqftH6f2shuJXOf27zflfKf6L7faUnctRTEDfTv7377evMPgfRPpB90pbNnu3nrU-rvM-0f7hbtTTDY7PNtqHs73nC7a-KPG-j5mvHcWOu--DnPElc735t3t7afaUwL5kaFe-N-rb-fh7sHVXgQcWuthnHvpd0Lr9dkeVPZnjiT7Ck1RMhpXPrU0l73cwAdRPcJI3c7C99+Lvbnku2t7Hc40dROpOWiX7oCP+4bZPt-2r6-8cAdReBLCl7bACeqKbeAXdxr5IC4UHcKKkQMb5hc-eYAqPhAPcI2R4ED0TqmXz-R98puJ-fgY+QySaxWydXYgQryrbydyBbfflmrAyRPdT2aArgSL3EH+8mebXAQXvTUxZcIeRRPQbwIMGE8BBDea4iIIT59dGB7bH-ht0CDCZMuAHLDpYNa7WDpBr9LuIkwKhwDnBFA1wVQJUz5h5mObMwf0QsGU8+Bhg6QUAw8G985OZAtboPzUHJJj8wQSdki3oEdMku3g-PogLyhwk8h+Q5fmILSEt8B+NHLIc-xsheFweogyHkUPiFWCC+kGLHmjCFraCJ+OvOIYzx8FdCRkPQhsN3wWYFCtOEvZgZQMJQhAlyRpX3hXwkHgDEhcBA0rZRe5sRohrQ8wTUK-4ZD6hqvQ9GP3Mi8p+h2XcPorwPbHCVeeHd9ExCXJ1Er+DjEgV2Qf4uCn+NSWFOZDizBCKumQ04d0P-5Y54+8vG4UoPSHK8JWjwx5K2Se7BdYBKwqHh0JGGIDRk2xUZHsIcFtDQB6IkoSwKxEUI3kb-a-ooM-5rCEhvgzYexBsbzNyeqQwDkrx544DxOoyWPmpnkE6CMBPAwkQgOJGvwsGY5VEe0OGFEj5hOyQxEYjeEjNKRB-OlBvWn6SCNhc6Y4BlDlxk8IR7-BUZ8NmGP8h+NSJofCRDrocWEe7FkXcNhG88dGOyLmOxFN7XC7OFHL4aEJ+HbJkCieUwfsIYFujVBIIsYbqSxyl88RIApwUCJOHwjD0WIoLjqIpFQiqR+gjEcSNGTeIecgI1vsCOjGQYRKk0IqE6JiHnk7+PnA0d8KNFcp1CcKC9rsJxYlij+WAq3qlxt6dpfEiBQsN10zF1CHhaXR5L4lRi+wWWrEeMe8L1H8iJRgoqUb4gWp+xOBAwljuOLz6TiwhhKbBqS0mEjj5RiY0gbUJUHZjexMYt5Imi7F7ioxB43MTznuhG4Tx9wuEeeJGTGIkRoYyEYn0OHUjOhmIxOvdFLJzjnRjg-0fuJbHvox6PKckaOO3GYDWR2A5sbgOAmMZzI8qQsb6MWKCd2a5o0Vo2Ld6n9NhR6YlJzBvE2j2Rdoo9AtW7hmjrmGHS0V4IFFzCVxRiLOE9AIlsiYJHI2FAmiOC4iXx-4sse6IrGriG82DJCWGP6LLcAJZ4oCX2Jq45hx+f4-ERGKzHiTYJkk01mNTFEEiJxtEj0auOPxjcD6QQtSfJO7F3iJJMYiKq2U4m6iIJokniQGJzEPiIqnMf7gZLEk9iTJuY4MYv12bMjqJGkw0Q0OcAcTDcQ40rs5JsmASlJh6V5AeEPLkS9WYdKiS5OMkRTIM8qTUZMNUnTDh4Mnb5j5KXGaS+JviD7K7UAFMjMpePSPh+OJEfZZA+pOXpZPL5ojfJ5Y-yXKiPE2V7BXEuSYlNtElNfEWcLHNn1KlVCupYUxSRyNGxXj42U7ecWF1X6YT1+UgzYXmHwyIi6xh-ZUcf3WG0i50hYTWDmGfH1TuJFUlMVKMLBwlS0TE6CTN16mFh8sgtTsaFOOmSi6J00WQWTyGkKCIJi4pgX5MDEBS+wB4NQp4O6lESbpTQ-EmBK3ENTxReU36XZP+ny5tYl0psddO1JqYQgf7EqRZITHQz1JsM5qX9O2S5wR8+sZGVhMWlzpc43pV+MDNGmuTkpIyW4mDzJkLS1RnaL1DYwOk4yjpKoraaMOcBepNRDYFmaqO2nszuUT+OUebwvy5SfpBM+GUTPUJTgfRwkwoXjLlm8SWpnqIqad1plPTlxWktTEVPmjBSseIsvmZiMpyTRtYQkzqQcKtHKDbxPUtGXFlkDAVzZNI-mUTKxxawcotsw6ZgTfHJjnphs+LKSIXIPSypEfXmZ7MtkG5FqHsyqVKOuIZRucU0yoZ9NxmGTTx9MjkYAQAH+zuZI0-WflK1kmCgmywqObcMdmESWJdomVr7MmHYzwJr4h2TCOYmoyviamEllQj0nNsq50I3cU7NBkuyhKWsHxInJOl0TOiQTdiJPJDkFS3kohaYnfW8kgy65vUt5Phi34ySixMwkuXDPvECz-880QaZuOlnRzNpsc4kSYgVSITfxe8i3vNNFlezCUpaN6VzJbk8yr5ScuiaWlspZkB5SY4oQbIKkPQ4SmEeeaArLk85GIi5SOcNPDHrzO5OJYxP-3Yhk9m5UM7+c-Itk3zJOHEKBaXMJlvyXa+sHYT7yAXatZZIQ2yUfO2QLkfYdUouUgrplJSORC5YlDZSIWHy3JIyBchjSQIPzkJrNGhZGNzl2j4FWUCOavKoWQTrRHcg3l3IhovIaZj0mOb-MNmLlM+U4HhfLPoVvyg83cLBRfMaJiKFJEi3qf2FkBLVC5X84uRoqnlaLfYrnExc72+m0LwpHC3KDymYX2LWFB8-RXwucBy49qNY4cXos1kkL50jEP2cItVm1o5pUElGUotQVtVJoEiWRYgrXr1iNpuC6+VKNJR7hHJdi7BQ4p-lOKwFx+ZiAgszk4Lkl5Mtme+lJSaiMkesxxQvJgX-44sWMyJXQuCXbIyCEjGpV5LkUeLxF7Cu0WQSXLYx1FFSzpdErIIJo5cLQhJQJyDkgLiFCswlMej3CjJP5ZSgJR0ugWLLQeO-UpaYsHlHDa5KC9wldXexSc5FSShRVdNSV3KFcSlDqQHM-K5Ls5w8jeWjKKjeUVZdsv0Wwudldyio28zCBcvcWrDg5Jy7ZUeh1o2Q-FhysFYEqiVIrGM3lDWH0q8VTKA6TWXeSIqfkNLWZYs99GazRjzQ1pSov5TcreWPkj0wfY9KbI+m8iPhzymuYotn7vLY+QMuZfks0UFSXcQTZAfEtBXFj1pDK3ldhLnQu4XyajbdtyvbmvK+VzKxyYmnZVorLlwCmibwoZnOBOYTLDJLCve7jKLFky3qZzAHFjcpZzvIYfjKxUGK2Co1KhHSvnZ5LyVL8zEathbJuLJ+vy5BUys2GnoapgvSVd8oxXHKtlrq09OQ3CUhSxl8KzZYao5Fjdil90rJXUvKXCrKlZcsbrZQqpyshVPqvBVKKejQZfYJKtZeVNjXpqplEVQWoNMDU69LVRkiFagqei2UKGZal5Sko1WbC4U3qC6WvPBUjyu5PJaRTyJmki9VVQ8xlUOrnRkNX+baljguuuVyqKZnaaSVeI3H4qxpdo8RllBtk5rOVeozde+ILXRKc4cCyGXqsVFerZV6q+VbuuuKbx2V58uFY1OdX9KjV2yLuKnIlWYxv173J1RrP-Uciu4xfPDAB3hroT9WmKqDcepUx1FD1litGblD2m0r+1PK19TuvfSxdx5uqn9TDMg0ErepGPVJLUnaXzLEVrq6jbUnZXrqwuEGzxUeqo0pIPsiLAqAcsfXyL8Ng6t9e+h5hMtcNci1CbqxtYrNkNlGtGTzDTLzQHVFq1NQaqCUAbCUimi4SVK+UsKY19GuNQMq03HACMgQvKPxrI3qyONmGrufqXbpdxEszIhDRRLVoNqNNHI-UuO3xLmrBhFzNCa5ownlqCldE-UkEyEoXdslKE-zdJoKoTqAVdm9HvNF80Li1NTUl1cZvbD4kE6JUh9Y6o2XqaMtmm9GAqnbCRbc1RywzY2t6ljt7orZFLbNODXxbblzK-ME931gqadeV6hFUZuK14ZSanq+-s1tDVzoEOh5SYXpv8U5KZVIa5dbhkmLHAv1GG61QppdpdxW1dG-NQsqRXPwaBYG9tWlr-Xya7NPsx8ZtuC0iqy5z8YviJV5irKpVoi2bSJseRRU0Yz5XWCCujXRa25i67dU0pe1kFpFlm8DTFuE7Da5tomwHYxibZ5RltXau5Tk1Hpk88tFq10eDue30YcwB4MiXhrVXCbCNL2rHaioa0i8O1OclbXZpcXHA+5jDSTaDsQ2yb3NRWzzSPQbAULFhcOydagobB7L2dHO3Hb9oI3-b6MeGaKYSQF1bqhdlKl7XvW5xk9Jt6KtWS+vx3C7IMi1btjfUW4S7r12211XNy1jdxalF6r6Ydoo2caFNRuBBCVP22pbf1Zu2zdzoip5QFdAm9jRMvh2tb-8QKknXyNN02aKdjuihLChd1WbldjS6XYekVyiE5oRuudRgLd1WqPdmwxXOZmfg+6PhZO-5S1uT2jJVMTklNXbv91J6508PBOiCxCD3avt+8pnSht6lUJbKZmJzQXvI1F6uddyuZo+3TkFRPt+mpXU9oJ2R7PCbydlSHtU2F73dbe5lfNG8S5ROdCW1BQYjvlAFjdWc-varpGQGIapOcc7QOvD2vz8SZTN2uXoylRbq9VWjzXaIz6v8k1QA0-WSt30Ur99ncTWEcFI1j6W9E++fe3s75ThgdB28fYnsn3J6fFhYa3TvqE177MRCLNGOjPPVx6M9fuz-dnpL2i6hKZPSvb3rP1baGNmWrfhcPmYo6-NP2yXSroj2QZmm7AmHX-tt0f7ADX+qfWPLdrma2l46uTebq7k2UsGkazGKPv-20HO1QBkva-Xmh86bdbGgreltr1oybK3iDlfAb1EJ6BD9B5PckMYxz7kDnaYxfdABGsGa9x2hfZbsXIVD8o1B7gYgboMaGhMDk64uAbx2QHiRCTJeiVIwNTa+96OgfeQZSQyD-YvBmg9ZqQMjbO0wQJhegfUOBH30wQeBAkzCMQ7HkPiUmkxS13N7-DFh8I3EaPTeZtRMRjHZBh8QvlbicB2SZVuwO9aORRuchlQdsOC7SD++xveZDf18GUjShyw3Ef-5epxddO4gzrpwPFazMqcyDtrp63Va0ZTeBfmIdJ3mHmjaRw9H2HMw+aIc2Rjw6Zn06dFj9vhswwAamOxGZjBuX2JUe3bWS2DDuu5fgJhQ37aNgxtNRft6l1F3si5RY+vucA2RilY-KNZgfv0QHH9mImyKa1p137615+5nXaJsgZRtYLTPjQ8bIOmZ24ahUI5ccK1SGu5GSXnEh0KOPyATJR4Y0iYbzU7ytK++pQ-t9XEi5o28zuIXkhO1HX6PaM+RSe+NAMpotJ4kwDMVXp6xxkx8ncXqCO6kq1eJ+Qybs2McnBDcaDGJ1weiMn5hGMM9mPRRHJGw9Xxlga-vwxLofD4plca-q5iHkm9-xy+ZieuPalX9TTE3rzHWO6CJDR29gziQ4lZreN+UHva4awMXab12yjic8lPmqmtJHEzUfFlZP8n+Dgp5QwSleSMQ+dchoowZt1NAmSmryLIhwNGXan1ohxvQxafcKvIgmBR0tbKbX1Qn6srZG7aIfdN8Sjg2xXSbHrDNuGjjAelM5jS1h5wLjhsJoCcA0DnAXAQAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Vega-Lite chooses "nice" domain boundaries, so that axes end on round numbers. If you want specific domain values without this additional adjustment, you can disable this behavior in the scale specification:

```
"scale": {"domain": [0, 2090], "nice": false}
```